# How to include social media sharing inside .NET MVC application?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter

I have an app that allows the user to add a journal entry. Under the journal entry pallet I want to have Twitter, Facebook and Google+ icons, which will share the entry on each respective service.

What library can I use to handle this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No need for a library. Each service provide easy to use code-snippets to include share-buttons for their service. Place each code-snippet in your view, where you want to have it.

- [Facebook Like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)
- [Twitter Tweet button](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/tweet-button/overview.html)
- [Google+ button](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/) *(Google+ will sunset on March 7, 2019, so this will soon be invalid)*

Comment: FOr the twitter one, how do I get the users to login before the tweet is sent?

Comment: @James I believe Twitter will take care of that for you. If the user isn't logged in already, she will be prompted to so before sending the tweet.

Comment: Twitter link is not working and Google+ will shut down soon

Comment: @YahyaHussein Thanks for letting me know. Have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the different JavaScript files for sharing your content then simply you can use this code, it is fast because no need to wait to load the JavaScript files from different sites, you need to download the different images which are easily available online

```
//facebook share
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?    
     u=@Url.Encode(Request.Url.ToString())&t=@Url.Encode(Title)" 
     target="_blank">
     <img src="/images/social-buttons/Facebook.png">
</a>

// twitter
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?
   url=@Url.Encode(Request.Url.ToString())&text=@Url.Encode(Title)" 
   target="_blank" title="Tweet">
   <img src="/images/social-buttons/Twitter.png">
</a>

// google
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?
   url=@Url.Encode(Request.Url.ToString())" 
   target="_blank" title="Share on Google+">
   <img src="/images/social-buttons/GooglePlus.png">
</a>
```

Comment: The title of the post you want to share

Answer (score 0):

Yes every service provider provide code in their developer area but you need to study and analyse separately one by one, here is all in one link.

**Linkedin Share :**

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-onsuccess="lnksuccess" data-onerror="error" data-url="<%=strShareUrl %>"></script>

**CallBack Function :**
 <script>
  function lnksuccess(url) {
    alert("url = " + url + "  shared successfully");
  }
  function lnkerror(url){
    alert("something goes wrong in url sharing");
  }
</script>
```

Check out this for more (Reference).

[Social share buttons for facebook, twitter, linkdin in asp.net](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2012/06/social-share-buttons-in-aspnet.html)